# Use a text file (containing file names) to copy files from current directory to new directory

Tags: linux, grep

I have created a file (`search.txt`) containing file names of `.fasta` files I want to copy from the current directory (which also contains many unwanted `.fasta` files). Is it possible to use this text file to find and copy the matching files in the current directory to a new location?

The search.txt file contains a list of names like this:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
```

I tried to build the search term using find and grep, like this:

```
find . *.fasta | grep -f search.txt
```

which is returning output like this for each matching file:

```
./name_1.fasta
./name_2.fasta
./name_3.fasta
name_1.fasta
name_2.fasta
name_3.fasta
```

It's finding the correct files, but I'm not sure if this output is useful / can be used to copy these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get only matching filenames from search.txt I would do this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.fasta' -print0 | grep -zf search.txt | xargs -r0 cp -t target-dir/
```

It will find all files with the extension .fasta, display only the ones with matching patterns in search.txt, and bulk cp them to target-dir, and each filename is terminated with a nullbyte in case filenames contain newlines.

Comment: This worked for me.  Have accepted this as answer as i found it easier to understand than @Benjamin W (which also worked).

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash, you can read all the files from the list into an array:

```
$ mapfile -t files < search.txt
$ declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="name_1" [1]="name_2" [2]="name_3")
```

Then, you can append the desired file extension to all array elements:

```
$ files=("${files[@]/%/.fasta}")
$ declare -p files
declare -a files=([0]="name_1.fasta" [1]="name_2.fasta" [2]="name_3.fasta")
```

And finally, move them to the desired location:

```
$ mv "${files[@]}" path/to/new/location
```

You don't actually need the intermediate step:

```
mapfile -t files < search.txt
mv "${files[@]/%/.fasta}" path/to/new/location
```